# Group by key in xslt 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to group by an attribute .
Example input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns1:map xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
  <ns1:string key="omschrijving">Inschrijfstaat Raamovereenkomst</ns1:string>
  <ns1:map key="concepten">
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/Document">
      <ns1:string key="iri">http://url/def/Document</ns1:string>
      <ns1:string key="naam">Create Document</ns1:string>
    </ns1:map>
  </ns1:map>
  <ns1:map key="collecties">
    <ns1:map key="4a9ff131-a507-4979-817a-09ae4365386a">
      <ns1:string key="uuid">4a9ff131-a507-4979-817a-09ae4365386a</ns1:string>
      <ns1:string key="naam">meeden</ns1:string>
    </ns1:map>
  </ns1:map>
  <ns1:map key="eigenschapConcepten">
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/4c20ec8e-8e86-30ca-89a0-96e8ecad447d">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">tekst</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="waarde">112</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/7d94197f-78b5-3f8f-9068-a99235fda655">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">tekst</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="waarde">nld</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/2c0bea42-27b1-35aa-aa93-c91d22a2a78e">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">tekst</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="waarde">Inschrijfstaat Raamovereenkomst</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="https://url/43514c35-3699-4cf2-abaa-ac2906c41e7f">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">tekst</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="waarde">G014485-BEG-2139</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/hasVersion">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">entiteit</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="entiteitUuid">cb020428-ec25-44f7-8add-7e334eb2a3c0</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="https://w3id.org/def/basicsemantics-owl#describes">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">entiteit</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="entiteitUuid">004ed20d-1292-4210-a541-755754497fbe</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="https://w3id.org/def/basicsemantics-owl#describes">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">entiteit</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="entiteitUuid">004ed20d-1292-4210-a541-755754497fba</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
  </ns1:map>
</ns1:map>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns1:map xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
  <ns1:string key="omschrijving">Inschrijfstaat Raamovereenkomst</ns1:string>
  <ns1:map key="concepten">
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/Document">
      <ns1:string key="iri">http://data.tennet.eu/def/Document</ns1:string>
      <ns1:string key="naam">Create Document</ns1:string>
    </ns1:map>
  </ns1:map>
  <ns1:map key="collecties">
    <ns1:map key="4a9ff131-a507-4979-817a-09ae4365386a">
      <ns1:string key="uuid">4a9ff131-a507-4979-817a-09ae4365386a</ns1:string>
      <ns1:string key="naam">meeden</ns1:string>
    </ns1:map>
  </ns1:map>
  <ns1:map key="eigenschapConcepten">
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/4c20ec8e-8e86-30ca-89a0-96e8ecad447d">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">tekst</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="waarde">112</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/7d94197f-78b5-3f8f-9068-a99235fda655">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">tekst</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="waarde">nld</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/2c0bea42-27b1-35aa-aa93-c91d22a2a78e">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">tekst</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="waarde">Inschrijfstaat Raamovereenkomst</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="https://url/43514c35-3699-4cf2-abaa-ac2906c41e7f">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">tekst</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="waarde">G014485-BEG-2139</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="http://url/def/hasVersion">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">entiteit</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="entiteitUuid">cb020428-ec25-44f7-8add-7e334eb2a3c0</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
    <ns1:map key="https://w3id.org/def/basicsemantics-owl#describes">
      <ns1:array key="eigenschappen">
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">entiteit</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="entiteitUuid">004ed20d-1292-4210-a541-755754497fbe</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
        <ns1:map>
          <ns1:string key="vullingType">entiteit</ns1:string>
          <ns1:string key="entiteitUuid">004ed20d-1292-4210-a541-755754497fba</ns1:string>
        </ns1:map>
      </ns1:array>
    </ns1:map>
  </ns1:map>
</ns1:map>
```

See the key "https://w3id.org/def/basicsemantics-owl#describes" is the one i am trying to group, but it can also be another duplicate key. So i can not pinpoint on a hardcoded value for the key.

I have tried a lot off which i found here and other websites but can't seem to make it work dynamically.

Thx for any help in advance.

Comment: Please explain which elements you want to group and by which value (relative to such an element). Also, what have you tried, how did it fail exactly? At which point can you define the grouping key, when running a particular stylesheet, or only while processing a particular input?

Comment: I want to group every duplicate key i come across with the <ns1:array key="eigenschappen"> like in the expected output.

Comment: Well, you have lots of `ns1:array key="eigenschappen"` so grouping `ns:array` elements on `@key` would group more than the two elements you seem to have merged.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is known to contain only those `ns1:array` children as part of an `ns1:map` then perhaps

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:map[fn:map/fn:array[@key = 'eigenschappen']]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="fn:map" group-by="@key">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:copy select="fn:array[@key = 'eigenschappen']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, current-group()/fn:array/*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

suffices.

Comment: Martin, you are a lifesaver. This works great.

Comment: What if i have other segments on the same level. The current xslt removes them

Comment: @JanH, consider to ask a new question with the input you have, the result you want, the code you have used and the wrong result you get.

Comment: Ah Tnx Martin, i was struggeling with the stackoverflow interface.I will do that